Helm ignore alias property in dependencies
I have a need to move my chart from an umbrella system to use one universal subchart, so as not to spawn identical subcharts that differ only in some values. I have left this chart identical to my previous subcharts using the umbrella system. In values.yaml the example of values for a certain service looks like this.
service1:
  enabled: true
  env:
    # List of envs
  service:
    # List of specific params

Chart.yaml of the general chart looks like this.
apiVersion: v2
name: meta-chart
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes

type: application

version: 1.0.0

appVersion: "1.0.0"
dependencies:
  - name: template-service
    alias: service1
    condition: service1.enabled
  - name: template-service
    alias: service2
    condition: service2.enabled
  - name: template-service
    alias: service3
    condition: service3.enabled
  - name: template-service
    alias: service4
    condition: service4.enabled

Issue: The helm template command works correctly. However, the result I get is not what I expected. Instead of an identical list as with the umbrella chart, I only get the resources of this template-service as output. Where is the error in my solution? Let me also clarify that I am calling the helm template to test the following command (I am passing two value files, one of which is generic for general settings, not service-specific, and does not contain a service-specific name or alias section).
The command for the helm template:
helm template release services/ -f services/values.common.yaml -f services/values.dev1.yaml -f services/secrets/secrets.dev1.yaml.enc

UPD1: I found a similar problem in issues, and the author it solved when added a version to each dependency. I also tried adding a version, but it didn't work for me.

I have never had good experiences with umbrella charts.  I'd consider deploying the individual services independently, or using a purpose-built tool like Helmfile.  Similarly, I wouldn't try to build a "universal chart" any more than I'd build a "universal program"; if every possible Kubernetes option is exposed as Helm values then you're basically back to directly writing Kubernetes manifests in the Helm values file.  Do you have an example of a specific include or template invocation that's failing?

@DavidMaze Regarding "example of a specific include or template invocation that's failing": A full example is unnecessary. The "template-service" subchart expands like others, because that subchart is identical like previous chart (now uses as aliases), but doesn't substitute values from its section. Regardless of enabled alias subcharts, helm template outputs only one resource from template-service instead of multiple resources (e.g., deployments, services, ingresses) with individual names and values as before.

@DavidMaze Thanks for the tip on Helmfile, I'm thinking of switching to using it in the future, but for now it's more important to solve the current problem at hand.

The problem was this. My charts directory was missing Chart.lock, which was causing the alias property to be ignored. Adding a Chart.lock file to the charts directory helped solve the problem. Although it is still strange that before using the umbrella system everything worked correctly without this file.
